# React settimeout function causing page to refresh repeatedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

My friends and I are trying to create a React App. In this scenario, we want to figure out what user is currently logged in and then send a post request to determine everyone that is in the same "room" as them and display it on the app when the page loads. We send our data back as an array. Though when we console.log our "response" we get multiple outputs. Furthermore, when we try doing setRoomies we get non-stop requests to our server.

Below I have provided our code for React, server, and as well as the console.

```
function Dashboard() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [roomKey, setRoomKey] = useState('')
    const [roomies, setRoomies] = useState('')

    setTimeout(function () {
        const currUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        if (currUser) {
            setEmail(currUser.email);
            setUser(currUser.name);
            setRoomKey(currUser.roomKey)
        } else {
            setUser(null)
        }

    }, 10);


    const payload = {
        roomKey: roomKey
    }
    setTimeout(async function () {
        const response = await axios({
            url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/dashboard',
            method: 'post',
            data: payload
        })

        // setRoomies(response.data.roommates)
        console.log(response.data.roommates)
    }, 10)
```

```
userRouter.post('/dashboard', async function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    const sendKey = req.body.roomKey

    user.find({ roomKey: sendKey }, await function (err, foundMates) {
        console.log(foundMates)
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                token: USER_LOGIN_FAIL
            })
        } else {
            console.log(foundMates);
            res.send({
                token: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                roommates: foundMates,
            })
        }
    })
})
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuHw9.png)

Comment: James you should use the react hook useEffect for side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use setTimeout like that. Instead you should use useEffect to achieve what you want. Might require some changes, but the idea is to do something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
       const currUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
       if (currUser) {
          setEmail(currUser.email);
          setUser(currUser.name);
          setRoomKey(currUser.roomKey)
       } else {
                setUser(null)
            }
    
       }, []);
    
useEffect(() => {
        if(!roomKey) {
          return;
        }
    
        const payload = {
            roomKey: roomKey
        }
        async function getInfo() {
            const response = await axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/dashboard',
                method: 'post',
                data: payload
            })
    
            // setRoomies(response.data.roommates)
            console.log(response.data.roommates)
        }
        getInfo();
}, [roomKey]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help